# Writing non-blocking DOM functions

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have some big amount of data to be processed. For the sake of this example, let's say that the data just can't be processed on the server side; it must be processed on the client side. Let's also say that the entire data process looks like this:

```
for element in data do:
    //do some work with "element"
end
```

Again, for the sake of this example, let's say that `data` contains 100.000 elements.

Calling the process function will freeze the entire DOM until the loop has reached it's end. My question is: is there some way I could do this processing in an non-blocking way? Be it some sort of async/wait, processing chunks of `data` with some type of `yield` mechanism, or pretty much anything else?

EDIT: Web Workers are not an option as I need at least IE 11 support.

EDIT 2: Seems I was mixing "Web Workers" with "Shared Web Workers". Question is answered.

Comment: Have you investigated WebWorkers for this purpose?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: @johnnyutah — They won't have access to the DOM.

Comment: @Quentin so? ........

Comment: @zerkms — So the question is asking about DOM functions and dealing with elements.

Comment: @Quentin I believe it is not. OP mentioned the loop blocks the whole browser, that is solved by webworkers.

Comment: Does putting the task into a seperate function with promises block the DOM? I thought it doesn't. Promises seem like a legit answer to this to me. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @aRsen49 yep - you're overlooking the fact that JS is single threaded, and promises just add indirection on how you retrieve results, nothing more.

Comment: @johnnyutah @ zerkms Ignoring if I must deal with the DOM from the processing loop, Web Workers are really shiny and cool, but none of the IE (not even Edge) versions support them, and, sadly, I must support at least IE 11. I will update the question in a moment.

Comment: @alexandernst are you sure? http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers

Comment: IE 10 and up and Edge support Web Workers

Comment: @zerkms Indeed, I was mixing this with "Shared Web Workers", which is what isn't supported in any IE versions at the moment. Ok, I think my question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop a given amount of elements each time, processing the next batch in the next stack. To accomplish this you must use `setTimeout`. That is quite rudimentary but works in any browser..
Maybe using reduce or something.. sending the rest to the next stack and so forth..

This article may help https://benjaminhorn.io/code/part-2-cpu-intensive-javascript-computations-without-blocking-the-single-thread/

This only can be considered the right answer if you cannot rely on web workers, since this is for what they were specified.